# Is it possible to configure IIS 7.5 output caching for an individual page?

Tags: iis, outputcache

We'd like to use [IIS 7.5 output caching](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching) for an individual .aspx file, but after some reading at iis.net, it seems to me the caching can only be configured for various file extensions, but not for individual files. Is that correct or did I miss something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just change view to "content" select file, and config it. In extension add eq .js or .php. This config will be only to this file.

You can check this in:

eq

web.config

```
<location path="cachedfile.php">
        <system.webServer>
            <caching>
                <profiles>
                    <add extension=".php" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:30:00" />
                </profiles>
            </caching>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```